# i want to retrive record whose last payment not received in last 3 month

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a customer table like Customer Name ,Customer, No File No and  Payment Table Customer File No , Amount , Date

How i fetch record in this table and also i want unique like customer paid many times in diff month i only want who not paid in 3 month based on current date

```
     $data = DB::table('installments')
    ->select('installments.client_reg_no', DB::raw('MAX(installments.date) as max_paid_date'))
    ->where('installments.date','>',$datem)
    ->groupBy('installments.client_reg_no')->get();

    $data=DB::table('customers')
    ->joinSub($lastinstallment, 'installments', function ($join) {
        $join->on('customers.file_no', '=', 'installments.client_reg_no');
    })->where('customers.status','=','1')->get();
```

Comment: Have you set up your customers table as a Model, and used a migration ?

Comment: yes i did and some how i manage to retirve but its in raw querry can you help me to do in elquent laravel querry builder